# bring second div in center is failing

Tags: html, css

Having Following code, M trying to bring the second div in the center, somehow it is not coming, i do not want to use margin in minus:

Here is html and css

```
 <div id="headerLeft">
    <div id="imgsection">
        <div class="logo"></div>
    </div>    
    <div id="usersection">
        <div class="user">Sign</div>
        <div class="location">Find</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

my CSS

```
#headerLeft {
    width:45%;
}
#headerLeft #imgsection {
    width:150px;
}
#headerLeft #imgsection .logo {
    background: url('../img/logo.png') no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    width:88px;
    height:71px;
    width:100px;   
}

#headerLeft #usersection {
    float:right; 
    width:200px;
    margin: auto;
}
#headerLeft #usersection .user {
    width:80px;
    float:left;
}
#headerLeft #usersection .location {
    width:80px;
    float:left;
}
```

check this fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/CF6kX/

the second one which is covered with id: usersection needs to be in between, currently it is appearing at the bottom

Comment: second div in the center? why not tell the id or class of your div?

Comment: its is the usersection id, which is troubling me

Comment: Are you expecting [this](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KzHbm) output?

Comment: no, see me edits, it is coming like this as of now wth current code,

Comment: Do you need it vertically centered or horizontally centered?

Comment: please add an image with the desired result. This question can have so many interpretations..

Comment: i already created a fiddle in my original question, please check

Comment: @samsu The fiddle is what's currently wrong. Provide a image with how you WANT it to work. Then we can provide an answer with the image as expected outcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the image section add property float:left ,increase headerleft width below is the code

```
  #headerLeft {
            width: 58%;
        }
        #headerLeft #imgsection {
            width:150px;
float: left;
        }
        #headerLeft #imgsection .logo {
            background: url('../img/logo.png') no-repeat;
            background-size: cover;
            width:88px;
            height:71px;
            width:100px;   
        }

        #headerLeft #usersection {
            float:right; 
            width:200px;
            margin: auto;
        }
        #headerLeft #usersection .user {
            width:80px;
            float:left;
        }
        #headerLeft #usersection .location {
            width:80px;
            float:left;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

remove float:right  from This CSS

```
 #headerLeft #usersection 
{
   float:right;  
   width:200px;
   margin: auto;
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/CF6kX/1/)